# Can I have more than one action in a single routemap?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I have the following route set up:

```
    context.MapRoute(
        "MyAccount_default",
        "MyAccount/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

and the following links:

```
/MyAccount/Access/Login
/MyAccount/Access/Logout
/MyAccount/Access/Register
```

Is there some way that I can create a routemap so that entering:

```
/Login
/Logout
/Register
```

Would direct the request to the MyAccount area, Access controller and Login/Logout or Register methods? If I have
the routemap then can it belong inside the routemap of the MyAccount area or does it need to be outside that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should be specific with your routes. If you want something outside of the standard routes, add those to your route tables.

```
context.MapRoute(
        "Login",
        "/Login",
        new { controller="Access", action = "Login"}
    );
```

Add that before your default route.
The other option is to use our default route, but in addition use something like the AttributeRouting project at https://github.com/mccalltd/AttributeRouting
and specify your additional route on your action methods in each controller.

note that you could code on your Login action method something like:

```
[GET("Login")]
public ActionResult Login()
{
}
```

so your default routes would be used and in addition this extended route. I believe that should work anyways :)